# Converting multiple JSON De-Serialised Dates in a Bootstrap Table

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, servicestack

I have a Bootstrap add-on call Bootstrap Table which is a fully functioned table that sorts, exports data etc from a JSON source using Service Stack. 90% of the data feeds in correctly, however dates are showing as "2009-04-29T16:55:09.0000000", which is incorrect. I need to find a way of converting this date time string into one that looks like a much more friendly format.

The code I've been trying to complete this with is as a tester before applying this to all the rows is:

```
function formatDate(unformatteddate) {
  var formatteddate = (date.getDate() + '/' + (date.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + date.getFullYear() + ' ' + date.getHours() + ':' + date.getMinutes() + ':' + date.getSeconds());
  return formatteddate;
};

alert(formatDate("2009-04-29T16:55:09.0000000"));
```

The alert is just an easier way for me to see what the output is, it's not a permanent fixture just a temporary way of viewing data. Eventually my aim to get this displaying in the table itself, replacing the incorrectly formatted date.

But this simply returns an error in Google tools:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: date is not defined

I've been experimenting with various different ways to do this in a JSFiddle using the raw, outputted html from the bootstrap table:

http://jsfiddle.net/W3R3W0LF666/sc61nezL/5/

Is there an easier way to do this that I can apply to each row of the table that will show the date and time in a more friendly format?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you have to pass a date object to a function with `new Date()` and your formatDate function variable should be a date in this case like that:

```
function formatDate(date) {

var formatteddate = (date.getDate() + '/' + (date.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + date.getFullYear() + ' ' + date.getHours() + ':' + date.getMinutes() + ':' + date.getSeconds());
return formatteddate;
};

//$('.startdate').text(formatDate($('.startdate').text()));

alert(formatDate(new Date("2009-04-29T16:55:09.0000000")));
```

[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/sc61nezL/6/)

Comment: That works great for the alert, but when applied to the table completely falls over. Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/W3R3W0LF666/sc61nezL/7/

Comment: Sorted it - needed to loop through each row in the table - that's great though thank you

Comment: glad that worked, if you need any help, do not hesitate